# Create additional contact details in GeoServer WMS capabilities document

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I'd like to have separate contact details in the GeoServer WMS capabilities for the provider of the service and the provider of the contained data.

When setting up a GeoServer WMS, it adds the general contact details at the  beginning of the Capabilities document:

```
<WMS_Capabilities>
    <Service>
    ...
    <OnlineResource/>
    <ContactInformation>
        <ContactPersonPrimary>
            <ContactPerson/>
            <ContactOrganization/>
        </ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPosition/>
        <ContactAddress>
            <AddressType/>
            <Address/>
            <City/>
            <StateOrProvince/>
            <PostCode/>
            <Country/>
        </ContactAddress>
        <ContactVoiceTelephone/>
        <ContactFacsimileTelephone/>
        <ContactElectronicMailAddress/>
    </ContactInformation>
    ...
    </Service>
    ...
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

Is it possible to add another contact information to the capabilities document?

When enabling a workspace, the provided details overwrite the general information but do not get added separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add another contact information to the capabilities document?

No, only one `ContactInformation` block is allowed according to the [WMS capabilities schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd), and it is the contact information for the service.

The way to get to contact information for a dataset provided by a service is to link to metadata for the dataset in the layer metadata, using a `MetadataURL`.

For details on how to link to metadata for a dataset see the GeoServer [Data settings > Layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layers.html#data-webadmin-layers) page.

Comment: Great. Thanks for this hint. Will check, how that works.